# CSS align issue

Tags: css, html

okay so i have a div and a span right next to each other by using display:inline-block.
But the problem is when i put things into the div, the span also moves down to align it. how can i stop this and keep the span up top next to the top of the div.

HTML:

```
<div id="meat">
HELLO
</div>

<span id="tomato">
HELLO
</span>
```

CSS:

```
#meat{
    width:713px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    margin-left:169px;
    display:inline-block;

}

#tomato{
    width:199px;
    border:3px solid #000;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

you can see my live example at [MYSITE](http://mattyc.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
float: right;
```

Instead of

```
display:inline-block;
```

On your span

Answer (score 1):

The span is moving down because its an inline element and by default vertically aligned to bottom, set:

```
vertical-alignment:top;
```

will solve your problem

so your code will look like

```
#tomato{
     width:199px;
     border:3px solid #000;
     display:inline-block;
     vertical-alignment:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `float: left;` on each one. This should align them towards the top.